# Elastic Search Sum aggregation with group by and where condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I am newbie in ElasticSearch.

We are currently moving our code from relational DB to ElasticSearch. So we are converting our queries in ElasticSearch query format.

I am looking for ElasticSearch equivalent of below query -

```
SELECT Color, SUM(ListPrice), SUM(StandardCost)
FROM Production.Product
WHERE Color IS NOT NULL 
    AND ListPrice != 0.00 
    AND Name LIKE 'Mountain%'
GROUP BY Color
```

Can someone provide me the example of ElasticSearch query for above?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You'd have a `products` index with a `product` type documents whose mapping could look like this based on your query above:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/products -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "Color": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ListPrice": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "StandardCost": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then the ES query equivalent to the SQL one you gave above would look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "Name",
          "query": "Mountain*"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "Color"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "ListPrice": 0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_color": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Color"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_price": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "ListPrice"
          }
        },
        "total_cost": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "StandardCost"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to sort on the sum of the aggregation? Basically to order by total_price in this example?

Comment: @ErdalG. In the `terms` aggregation you can add this: `"order":{"total_price":"desc"}`

Comment: @Val Yes perfect! Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you so much.  This has been driving me nuts.

Comment: Note that you may need to include "size" (with a large value) inside the "terms" aggregation json or this will only return sums for the top colors, not all of them.